# Room Detection on a Tilemap

Tags: algorithm, monogame, tilemap

I am working on a 2D top-down game inspired by [Prison Architect](https://store.steampowered.com/app/233450/Prison_Architect/).
What I just can't wrap my head around is recognizing rooms built by the player.

The game is built on a tilemap, meaning the map is always a rectangle, while the rooms can be of any shape. I'd like to be able to detect whenever walls & doors create a new wall, like in the example below.

[image: Example room partition]

Since I have no formal education in CS (yet), I can't think of any algorithm or class of algorithms that might be of use here and also can't figure out one by myself. So if you have any ideas, suggestions or resources, I'd be very thankful!

In case this is relevant, I am using a custom implementation of a tilemap using [Monogame, a reimplementation of XNA](https://www.monogame.net/) and [Nez](https://github.com/prime31/Nez).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of depth-first search implemented in python, finding all squares of the same type and connected to a given input square:

```
maze = """\
*********
*    * **
*    D  *
**D*** **
*    * **
*   **  *
**   D  *
*********""".split('\n')

dr = [-1, +1, 0, 0]
dc = [0, 0, -1, +1]

def all_tiles_of_same_type(maze, r, c):
    tile_type = maze[r][c]
    tiles = set()
    todo = [(r, c)]
    while len(todo) > 0:
        cell = todo.pop()
        if cell in tiles:
            continue
        tiles.add(cell)
        r, c = cell
        for i in (0, 1, 2, 3):
            r2 = r + dr[i]
            c2 = c + dc[i]
            add_nbr = (0 <= r2 and r2 < len(maze) and
                       0 <= c2 and c2 < len(maze[r2]) and
                       maze[r2][c2] == tile_type)
            if add_nbr:
                todo.append((r2, c2))
    return tiles

print sorted(all_tiles_of_same_type(maze, 1, 1))
print sorted(all_tiles_of_same_type(maze, 3, 3))
```

Here are the main ideas:

- `tiles` keeps track of the result, adding squares as they are discovered
- `todo` holds a list of squares that must be visited in the future
- When we visit a square, we add all its neighbors to the `todo` list—or rather, all the *relevant* (same-type) neighbors. That happens in `for i in (0, 1, 2, 3): ...`.
- If we have already visited a square we should not visit it again, otherwise we will go into an infinite loop. That's what `if cell in tiles: continue` does.
- What makes this a depth-first traversal is our use of a stack: `cell = todo.pop()` removes from the end of `todo`, and `todo.append(...)` adds to the end as well. If instead we had used a queue, we would've done a breadth-first traversal.

Note that we don't explicitly construct a tree—but we could: whenever we add a neighbor of `(r, c)` to the `todo` list (and that neighbor hasn't already been visited), add an edge from `(r, c)` to the neighbor. Use the `(r, c)` given as inputs as the root of the tree. That would be the DFS traversal tree.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did work out!

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you want to compute the regions of your map that would be flood-filled in a paint program.  In that case, I recommend one of the following approaches:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

In case of the disjoint set data structure, you would union together each pair of neighboring grid cells. Once you have done that for all pairs, two squares `s1` and `s2` are in the same room if `Find(s1) == Find(s2)`.

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to describe it. But as far as I can tell, the algorithms you've pointed out are all related to trees, while my tilemap is stored in a simple array. How would I go about converting it to a tree, and wouldn't that be very CPU-intensive?

Comment: As I said in my other answer, we don't explicitly construct a tree. The X-first search algorithms run in time proportional to the number of vertices and edges (squares and neighbor-relationships); the disjoint set forest use only marginally more time. With respect to caches, a good rule of thumb is that sequential memory reads are fast compared to reads all over the place; so a simple forward for-loop through an array is fast, where visiting a tree is slow. However, always always always measure when doing performance work, 'cause it's complicated and we don't have good (enough) models.